# how do i show windows.alert("msg") after send a response to jsp from servlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

A user sends a request to servlet, and the servlet sends a response back to jsp,
i also want to show alert("message") on jsp after the servlet response to jsp,
how should i do? please help me, thank you.

```html
<FORM method="post" action="/test/Application.do">  
  <input type="submit" value="cancel" onclick="return confirm('sure?')"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cancelApp"/>
</FORM>
```

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
  req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  res.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  String action = req.getParameter("action"); 
  if (action.equals("cancelApp")) {

    //to something with database 

    String url = "/front-end/Application_Topping_MainPage.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, if the page 'front-end/Application_Topping_MainPage.jsp' is only visible as a result of this action, just add below code snippet in the jsp file.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){alert('message')}
</script>
```

if this page maybe visited by other manner other than post the form, and you only want the alert show after post, you can add such code in your jsp file.

```
<% if (flag) { %>
  <script>
    window.onload = function(){alert('message')}
  </script>
<% } %>
```

And in your doPost set that flag to be true accordingly.